# Displaying Youtube Videos From multiple channels ids

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, youtube-channels

How do I query multiple Youtube channels to get their videos?
Actually i did something like this to get video but this works perfectly when query only one channel.

```
private void getVideoResponce(String channelId)
    {

        Filters = new HashMap<>();
            Filters.put("part", "snippet");
            Filters.put("channelId",channelId));
            Filters.put("maxResults", "10");
            Filters.put("order","date");
            Filters.put("type", "video");


                final Call<VideoListResponse> getVideoResponse=CustomApplication.getYoutubeClient().getService().getVideoResponse(OAuthToken, Filters);

                getVideoResponse.enqueue(new Callback<VideoListResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<VideoListResponse> response) {


            if(response.isSuccess())
            {
String NextToken=response.body().getNextPageToken();
                    youtubeVideoFragment= new YoutubeVideoFragment(OAuthToken, "",myarr, mList);
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.videolistframelayout, youtubeVideoFragment, "YoutubeVideoFragment")
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                            .commit();

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Video failure Response -> "+ t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

But now i want to query multiple channel ids to get their video. How can i achieve this goal ?

Comment: Why not calling `getVideoResponce` while looping a list of channels?